# css elements aligment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position few elements correctly, here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Tjz6D/

Now the problem is that `block_under` doesn't go below image, i've noticed that if delete all floats everything is fine but i need floats for two divs that contains text to be in the same level as image.

So what's causing `block_under` to overlap with image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `clear` property:

```
#block_under{
    outline:1px solid green;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clear:both` on the `block_under` element.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Tjz6D/1/